# Store and retrieve the dynamically populated drop-down list in a localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have a drop down list which is populated dynamically. I send some ajax request and get response and based on a condition the drop-down is populated.
Now I need to store these populated list in localStorage as I will need to display the values which were populated previously on page refresh.

Everything works fine except that I am getting only the last value populated in the drop-down list. Not all the values which were populated previously. I need to retrieve all the values which were populated previously.

**index.jsp**

```
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" value="Display all" checked onclick="fnCheck();"> Display All

<input type="radio" class="radioButton" value="Display Divisions" onclick="fnCheck();"> Display Divisions


    <input type="radio" class="radioButton" value="Display Data" onclick="fnCheck();"> Display Data 
    <select id="convoy_list">
    <option>Values</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="testbtn" value="Test" onclick="fnClickTest();" >
    <input type="button" id="ok" value="OK" onclick="fnOK();" >
    <input type="button" id="Refresh" value="Refresh" onclick="fnDisplay();"
```

**myjs.js**

```
function test(){
    $.ajax({
    //some requests and data sent
    //get the response back

    success:function(responsedata){
        for(i=0;i<responsedata.data;i++):
        {
            var unitID=//some value from the ajax response
            if(somecondition)
            {
                var select=$(#convoy_list);
                $('<option>').text(unitID).appendTo(select);
                var conArr=[];
                conArr=unitID;
                test=JSON.stringify(conArr);
                localStorage.setItem("test",test);
            }
        }
    }
    });
}
```

In another function say display() i try retrieving the localStorage values

```
    function display(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("test")){
    var listId=$(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test")));
    var select=$(#convoy_list);
        $('<option>').text(listId).appendTo(select);

    }
```

Here if the data populated in the drop down list is C1 C2 and C3 for an instance. After i refresh the page only C3 is populated in the drop-down . I want all the values ie C1,C2,C3 to be populated back after refresh. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David said you are overwriting the item in localStorage. The key which you name should always be unique. The value of the key is changing at every iteration but not the key name. Hence to store it you will need to use a key with different names at each iteration.
Instead of using

```
localStorage.setItem("test",test);
```

use

```
localStorage.setItem("test"+i,test);
```

This will definitely not overwrite. And while retrieving use this in your display()

```
function display(){
for(var i=0;i<localStorage.length;i++){
    if(localStorage.getItem("test"+i)){
    var listId=$(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"+i)));
    var select=$(#convoy_list);
        $('<option>').text(listId).appendTo(select);

    }
  }
}
```

This will append all the values in your drop-down list which was previously populated.

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the item in the localstorage with every iteration because the key is always 'test'.

You could change the key to:

```
localStorage.setItem("test-"+i,test);
```

This would make them unique and all the values would be stored. You might want to change the key to something a little more descriptive.

Or you just store the response from your ajax call then create a function that forms the drop down lists, that can be called both in the ajax success and in your display function.

Comment: ok if i change the key to this how would I retrieve it? again a for loop then i should use localStorage.getItem("test"+i);>??

Comment: You could also store the value of i so it will only save the highest iteration then you could loop round again

Comment: But, How do we get the selected option while retrieving from local storage?